# I need some idea to correct this VBS code

Tags: vbscript

Hello everyone.
Hope everyone is fine.

I need help with this code below with the section (comment line) saying "'Help needed from here'":

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LocalTime")
For Each objItem in colItems

MsgBox "Welcome to the ALARM tool",0+0,"ALARM tool"
MsgBox "Note: 1) If the computer is given a shutdown or a restart command then the alarm will be disabled. 2) This ALARM tool dosen't support decimals & words. If you will enter a decimal, the elapsed message box will appear without processing the alarm due to the error. If you enter words then an error message will appear.",0+0,"ALARM tool"
thour=InputBox ("Type which hour you want the alarm to elapse in 24-hour format from 0 to 23 inclusive (not 24; instead 0): (E.G: 19, 15)","ALARM tool")
If thour="" Then
 MsgBox "The value is empty, so no alarm is set.",16,"ALARM tool"
 WScript.Quit
End If

tmin=InputBox ("Type which minute you want the alarm to elapse from 0 to 60 inclusive:","ALARM tool")
If tmin="" Then
 MsgBox "The value is empty, so no alarm is set.",16,"ALARM tool"
 WScript.Quit
End If

c=InputBox ("Enter your comment; leave it blank if you don't want one:","ALARM tool")

If c="" Then
 MsgBox "Time: ''"+thour+":"+tmin+"''       Comment: None",0,"ALARM tool: Preview"
Else
 MsgBox "Time: ''"+thour+":"+tmin+"''       Comment: ''"+c+"''",0,"ALARM tool: Preview"
End If

co=MsgBox ("Are you sure?",36,"ALARM tool")
If co="7" Then
 MsgBox "Alarm cancelled!!!",0,"ALARM tool"
 WScript.Quit
End If

'Help needed from here'

Do
If thour=objItem.Hour Then
 If tmin=objItem.Minute Then
  If c="" Then
   MsgBox "ALARM set to elapse on "+thour+":"+tmin+" has elapsed!!!",0+0,"ALARM set to elapse in "+t
   WScript.Quit
  Else
   MsgBox c,0+0,"ALARM set to elapse in "+t
   WScript.Quit
  End If
 End If
End If

'No more help needed after this'

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "There's an error while setting the alarm. Maybe you typed words or it's an internal error. Please try again. Sorry for the inconvenience.",0,"ALARM tool"
 WScript.Quit
End If
Loop
Next
```

You can give me the answer while even use it for yourself.
**Topic:** Alarm for specific time
I will say thanks for helping me and it *will* be a very good help.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: If you want your script to display a message box at a certain time, it'll need to keep running until the time arrives. You'll need to keep your script alive. Use `WScript.Sleep` to sleep until it's time to fire your alarm or use `WScript.Sleep` in a loop to check the time every so often. Personally, I would just have my script schedule a new task in Task Scheduler. Then you no longer need to keep track of the time. Let Windows do it.

Comment: **Asker:** You guys didn't understand. @Bond I have another file with the `wscript.sleep` command named "Alarm tool (v 3.0).vbs" but this is "Alarm tool for **specific time**". Did you say it can schedule tasks?Please give me the code then. The **WHOLE** problem will be solved.

Comment: If _we_ didn't understand, it's because _you_ didn't make it clear. :) You can use the `SCHTASKS` command to schedule a task to run at a specific time. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Hey all! I was... a kid back then (now too). Now I got the idea of what @Bond is saying. Thanks again!